# Use MS Word VBA to increase weight of axes in graph embedded in a Word document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am able to control the weight of a graph in *Excel VBA* using the following code:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
With Selection.Border
    .ColorIndex = 57
    .Weight = xlMedium
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
```

When I try running this in *Word VBA*, I get the error

**Compile error: 
Method or data member not found**.

**.Border** is highlighted.

I experimented with the code

```
salesChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
Selection.Borders(wdBorderBottom).Visible = True
```

and got the message

**Run-time error '4605' 
This method or property is not available because the object refers to a drawing object.**

I want to figure out a way to highlight the axes in the graph I'm embedded in a MS Word document through Word VBA

Comment: What is the origin of this chart? If it is from a copy/paste-special (enhanced metafile) you may not be able to access the same properties/etc. that are available to a full-blown MS Excel chart.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidZemens

It's an embedded graph generated within Word:

    Dim salesChart As Chart
    Dim chartWorkSheet As Object
    
    Set salesChart = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    Set chartWorkSheet = salesChart.ChartData.Workbook.WorkSheets(1)

You may have put your finger on the problem, in which case I'll have to go back to opening Excel from within Word and using VBA code preplaced there, which works like a charm, of course. It's a shame, though. Opening and closing Excel is much more of a time drag, as well as being somehow inelegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few things now that I look at this more closely. The first snippet is *Excel* code, this doesn't run and can't run in Word, and in fact it's raising a *compile* error.

> When I try running this in Word VBA, I get the error

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
With Selection.Border
    .ColorIndex = 57
    .Weight = xlMedium
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
```

The compiler highlights `.Border` because there is no `Border` property of a `Selection` object in Word.

The `Selection` object is a bit ambiguous, [because it can be different things](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821411.aspx). Think of it like a variant which refers to whatever is selected or the cursor point if nothing is selected.

So that explains the `method or data member not found` which isn't a run-time error, but a compile error suggesting that your code cannot possibly execute as-is.

If you replace `Select` and `Selection` with the object itself, like so:

```
With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Border
    .ColorIndex = 57
    .Weight = xlMedium
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
```

You'll get another error, because there is no such thing as `ActiveChart` in Word, that is an Excel object only. (Using `Option Explicit` would have alerted you to this problem). In word, you need to refer to the shape or chart, and you can do this with a handle on the shape as you have done, with a variable.  Try:

```
With salesChart.Axes(xlCategory).Border
    .ColorIndex = 57
    .Weight = xlMedium
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
```

This might be useful:

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

While written for Excel specifically, it is a better programming concept: `Select` is a pretty crude way of doing most things, and although there are some exceptions, nearly everything you can do with VBA can be done more efficiently by directly working with the object, rather than first *selecting* and then acting on the *selection* -- it's redundant. It's also messy because you need to constantly keep *selecting* things and your code is necessarily ambiguous, referring to vague `Selection` object (variant) rather than strongly typed object, etc.

Comment: Bull's eye! Thanks for the answer... and for the lesson.